# Apportable: release.keystore cannot be found

Tags: android, apk, keystore, apportable

I typed the following in the directory of my Xcode project:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias mykey -keyalg RSA \
        -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then, the following again:

```
BUILD=release ANDROID_KEYSTORE=release.keystore \
        ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword apportable build
```

And now pretty much everything compiled and looked good until one last fatal error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: release.keystore 
    (No such file or directory)
```

I have *double checked*, this keystore exists in both my Xcode project folder and in `.android`. I have double checked that the keystore name is correct, and the password is correct.

What could possibly be wrong?
Where should I be putting the keystore? I haven't a clue why it's not being found.

Comment: Your keystore file is mising. Check that correct directory is provided or not

Comment: I typed `keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias mykey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` multiple times in my xcode project directory, and it says that it already exists. Specifically `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias <mykey> already exists` How can I make sure that my keystore file is created? I'm not experienced. I simply copied what was in the apportable documents

Comment: Try creating a keystore with different name as this already exists

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Thanks. I read the app-signing documentation, but I still get this error when trying to compile with a keystore. I've tried deleting keystores, remaking keystores with different names, checking passwords, and so far nothing as worked. Do I need to use "jarsigner" before I build it with apportable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping. I'm inexperienced, so I run into newbie issues often. I got it to work by putting in the absolute path on my hard drive.

instead of

`ANDROID_KEYSTORE=release.keystore`

I typed

`ANDROID_KEYSTORE=/Users/carljalal/Desktop/OldGames/SuperSpeedApportable/release.keystore`

which is the path on my hard drive, and it worked.